# Correct way to encapsulate through generic interfaces

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface, encapsulation

My application consist of server and client, which are independant. They communicate through objects created and modified by server. Client is provided with read-only interfaces of this objects. As far as I know, that's the correct way to keep encapsulation in OOP. See example:

```
// Client-side

interface IBox<T> where T : ITool
{
    IEnumerable<T> Tools { get; }
}

interface ITool
{
    void Use();
}

// Server-side

class Box : IBox<Tool>
{
    public List<Tool> ToolList = new List<Tool>();

    public IEnumerable<ITool> Tools
    {
        get { return ToolList; }
    }
}

class Tool : ITool
{
    string _msg = "default msg";
    public string Msg
    {
        get { return _msg; }
        set { _msg = value; }
    }

    public void Use()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tool used! Msg: {0}", _msg);
    }
}
```

As you see, I have to use generics, because my objects form a hierarchy.

That looked nice, until I've decided to add a `Room` class with interface `IRoom`, which have to generalize not only `IBox`, but `ITool` too:

```
interface IRoom<B, T>
    where B : IBox<T>
    where T : ITool
{
    IEnumerable<B> Boxes { get; }
}

class Room : IRoom<Box, Tool>
{
    public List<Box> BoxList = new List<Box>();

    public IEnumerable<Box> Boxes
    {
        get { return BoxList; }
    }
}
```

Now, imagine that we have a `Room` consist of not only boxes. I need at least 3 collections of absolutely different things there, which are collections of several types too. So, there must be a huge tree, and my root class become something like: `Room : IRoom<Box, Tool1, Tool2, Tool3, Wardrobe, Coat, Jeans, Hat, Table, Computer, Book, Pen>`

I'm not sure, that is right. So, I'm asking, what is true OOP-way of implementing my task? (with no reflection, breaking encapsulation, type casting or other bad tricks)

Comment: Are you sure you need to use generics??? They're not to form hierarchy, they're to work with many different types. But since you've got interfaces and it looks all your type parameters need to be a single interface type, you can just use the interfaces avoiding generics.

Comment: I'd have `Room` have a `List<IRoomItem>` and every class of objects I want to put into the room implements `IRoomItem`. Likewise with `Box` and `IBoxItem`.

Comment: @Daniel I'm sure I need type-safety, encapsulation and functionality described in the topic: server creates and modifies, client reads. Both are independant. Please, propose the way with no generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the .NET Framework 4 and C# 4 you can use IEnumerable's covariance and just avoid using generics.

```
// Client-side

interface IBox
{
    IEnumerable<ITool> Tools { get; }
}

interface ITool
{
    void Use();
}

// Server-side

class Box : IBox
{
    public List<Tool> ToolList = new List<Tool>();

    public IEnumerable<ITool> Tools
    {
        get { return ToolList; } // With .NET 3.5 and earlier cast here is neccessary to compile
        // Cast to interfaces shouldn't be so much of a performance penalty, I believe.
    }
}

class Tool : ITool
{
    string _msg = "default msg";
    public string Msg
    {
        get { return _msg; }
        set { _msg = value; }
    }

    public void Use()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tool used! Msg: {0}", _msg);
    }
}


interface IRoom
{
    IEnumerable<IBox> Boxes { get; }
}

class Room : IRoom
{
    public List<Box> BoxList = new List<Box>();

    public IEnumerable<IBox> Boxes
    {
        get { return BoxList; } // and here...
    }
}
```

Covariance and contravariance in generics described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Comment: I thought that List<Tool> can not be IEnumerable<ITool> and your code will not compile... But it somehow does. Magic. Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised, but there's no need to cast (or may be I've misunderstood this term?). I mean, that your code works as is. No need to call `ToolList.Cast<ITool>()`, or `(IEnumerable<ITool>)ToolList`

Comment: Maybe it will compile but not run, I believe you need to do that cast. But I'd choose the cast as better option than generics.

Comment: Well....maybe the C# version you are using is newer than mine....mine demands `(IEnumerable<ITool>)ToolList` to compile.